# Convert docx to text files and save them in same folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program that needs to loop through a bunch of files in a directory, and convert the .docx and .pdf files to .txt. The difficulty is the files need to be renamed as well. I wrote a function to convert docx to text, then save them to the same folder. Once I get that working, I will expand it to pdf. The functions and code run, but no .txt file is created, and in the absence of an error description, I haven't been able to figure out why. Any help would be appreciated!

*Note: The code does find a bunch of .docx files that need to be converted. It just doesn't seem to create the new .txt versions of them
    #import a module to convert word to text
    import textract

```
#define a function that takes a word doc, a title and converts it to text
def to_text(word_doc_path,title):
    tmp_text = textract.process(word_doc_path, extension = 'docx')
    new_file = open(title,'wb')
    new_file.write(tmp_text)
    new_file.close()

#import modules for paths and regex
import os
import re

#define paths
path = 'C:\\my\\path\\'

files = []
# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
for file in f:
    if '.docx' in file:
        files.append(os.path.join(r, file))


for f in files:
    #regex to find name of pxx
    pxx = re.search(r'(?<=pxx )(.*)(?=\\)',f)
    #regex to find cxx
    cxx = re.search(r'[A-Z]{4} [0-9]{3}(?<![A-Z]{5})(?![A-Z])',f)
    #regex to find txx and year
    y_term = re.search(r'[0-9]{4} fxx|[0-9]{4} sxx',f)
    if y_term is not None and pxx is not None and cxx is not None:
        tmp_title = y_term.group(0)+'-'+pxx.group(0)+'_'+cxx.group(0)+'.txt'
        to_text(f,tmp_title)
```

Answer (score 0):

Attempt1 : It's seems to be a regex issue, if one of your search function return None, file is not created.

Attempt 2 : tmp_title is a filename, but not a full path, did you check if your file are not created in the same folder as your script is?

Comment: Hi Florian, I think the regex works - if I print (tmp_title), I get a few hundred results (which is correct)

Comment: @NLourme, a path issue?